# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException -unable to find valid certificat ion path to requested target]

Tags: java, exception, ssl, ldap, sslhandshakeexception

I am getting below error while I am connecting to LDAP server,I have imported the SSL certificate to //jre/lib/security. I am able to connect to server when running the program from JDK/bin file but outside that I am not able to execute it. I ahd set both JAVA_HOME and path variable to the same jdk where I have imported the certificate.

server on which I am trying to  this program is windows server, 32 bit , sevice pack 2.

> Unknown LDAP Error javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind
>   failed: saata
>   01.corp.oncor.com:1636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException : sun.security.validator.ValidatorException :  PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException : unable
>   to find valid  certification path to requested target]

Comment: An SSL certificate often comes with one or more additional files containing a certificate chain for the intermediate issuers of your SSL certificate.  Did you import that?